# I was doing the naïve approach for 2300 problem in leetcode. I couldn't solve it for a certain test case

Tags: arrays, sorting, pointers

https://leetcode.com/problems/successful-pairs-of-spells-and-potions/
problem link.

> You are given two positive integer arrays spells and potions, of length n and m respectively, where spells[i] represents the strength of the ith spell and potions[j] represents the strength of the jth potion.
>
> You are also given an integer success. A spell and potion pair is considered successful if the product of their strengths is at least success.
>
> Return an integer array pairs of length n where pairs[i] is the number of potions that will form a successful pair with the ith spell.

Code:

```
class Solution {

    public int[] successfulPairs(int[] spells, int[] potions, long success) {

        int n = spells.length;
        int m = potions.length;

        int pairs[] = new int[n];

        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            int successful = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j<m; j++) {
                int prod = spells[i]*potions[j];
                if(prod >= (int)success) {
                    successful++;
                }
            }
            pairs[i] = successful;
        }

    return pairs;

    }
}
```

I went through 2 arrays (spells and potions) using for loops. Gave a if condition to check if the product(spells[i]*potions[j]) can be greater then success and had a counter for every pair. basically the naïve approach. But it didn't work for a certain test case (48th one).

My solution worked for 47 solutions. This isn't a TLE. The expected answer is very different from my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use postfix. Here is my solution

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] successfulPairs(int[] spells, int[] potions, long success) {
        int[] postfix = new int[100001];
        for(int potion: potions) postfix[potion]++;
        for(int i=99999; i>=0; --i) postfix[i] += postfix[i+1];

        for(int i=0; i<spells.length; ++i){
            long val = success / (long) spells[i];
            if(success % (long) spells[i] != 0) val++;

            if(val <= 100000) spells[i] = postfix[(int) val];
            else spells[i] = 0;
        }
        return spells;
    }
}
```

[image]

It has a time complexity of O(n+m) while your bruteforce approach is O(nm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast spells[i] and potions[j] to long and declare prod as long. I faced a similar problem and typecasting to long long (in c++) did it for me. But I doubt if your solution will work or not because of the O(n*m) time complexity. The constraints ask for a O(nlogn) or better solution. You will probably get a TLE on some later testcases. Also no need to typecast success to int.